# Android Volley Save Data Twice

Tags: android, android-volley

Volley save data twice in database. This is my code. I added setRetryPolicy but ı got the same result. Also I use android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my manifest.

```
  public void RegisterInfo() {


            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

            parameters.put("name_surname",name_surname );
            parameters.put("email",email);


            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(parameters);


            final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,registerURL , jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
            }) { };
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    30000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
```

I called this function inside google sign result function;

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(LoginActivity.this);
            if (acct != null) {
                name_surname = acct.getDisplayName();
                email = acct.getEmail();
                RegisterInfo();
            }

        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you are calling RegisterInfo() ? Paste that code also .. Make sure you are't calling it twice...

Comment: @PraveenSP ı added code but ı control it. It called only one time.

Comment: @PraveenSP thanks for useful comment. I have mistake in my .php file. I realized my mistake. There is no any error in code. Thanks.